# Is there any ipdb print pager?

Tags: python, debugging, printing, pager, pdb

I am using `ipdb` to debug a python script.

I want to print a very long variable. Is there any ipdb pager like `more` or `less` used in shells?

Thanks

Comment: Save it to a file in the debug session and examine it with a proper text editor?

Comment: What is wrong with just printing it and scrolling up your terminal window?

Comment: The fact is that the variable can be thousands of lines long, to display it requires thousands of lines in the terminal buffer. Also, I'd prefer to not use a file, to have directly my output in the debugger..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to create a function which accepts a text, puts this text into a temporary file, and calls `os.system('less %s' % temporary_file_name)`.

To make it easier for everyday use: Put the function into a file (e.g: `~/.pythonrc`) and specify it in your `PYTHONSTARTUP`.

Alternatively you can just install `bpython` (`pip install bpython`), and start the bpython shell using `bpython`. This shell has a "pager" functionality which executes `less` with your last output.

Comment: bpython is awesome.. I'll try it and in case accept the answer.. +1